# Different element serialization styles for empty strings

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I'd like to understand how to get this different serialization for an empty string:

```
<root>
  <element1 />
  <element2></element2>
</root>
```

I tried to set some serialization attributes in my C# object but always have `element1` style.

- `[DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false, Name = "element3")]`
- `[XmlElement("element3", IsNullable = true)]`

Comment: Why do you care about the style? They are identical in terms of XML and the first one takes up less storage.

Comment: @DavidG I have a touchy client who doesn't support `element1` style, so I need `element2` style.